# How do you ReDim the first dimension in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: vba

It appears as if I can do this:

```
ReDim Preserve myarr(1,x)
```

But not this:

```
ReDim Preserve myarr(x,1)
```

Is this behaviour intentional? If so how do I get around it?

Comment: you can't: dynamic dimensioning lets you change an array last dimension only.

Comment: yup. sorry. Find an alternative way to know the max value of the first dimension before you Dim it.

Comment: You can flip your array around (provided you don't need to redim preserve both dimensions) or create a function to copy your array into a new (larger) array of the required size.  Difficult to say which approach would be "best" without knowing your exact use case.

Comment: ...or use an array of arrays instead of a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose the array first, then alter it, then transpose it again so its in the original format.

```
Public Function TransArr(arr As Variant) As Variant 
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, j As Long, k As Long 
    Dim tmpArr As Variant 
        j = UBound(arr, 2) 
        k = UBound(arr, 1) 
        ReDim tmpArr(j, k) 
        For x = 0 To j 
            For y = 0 To k 
                tmpArr(x, y) = arr(y, x) 
            Next y 
        Next x 
        TransArr = tmpArr 
End Function
```

Worth noting that in Access-vba - the .getrows method dum,ps a recordset into an array pre-transposed.